# Calling a Method from Constructor Method - Java

Tags: java, constructor

I've started learning Java and I have some homework that I need help with.

I'm making a program where it calculates the cost to paint walls and I need to call some methods from a constructor method.

I've looked at [this](https://howtodoinjava.com/oops/java-constructors/) article but it didn't really help.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class RenovationProjectManager { 

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int selection;
        String tempInput;

        String menu = "Menu: (type 1 or 2 to continue)\n";
        menu += "1. Calculate paint required for a wall\n";
        menu += "2. Calculate paint required for project";
        tempInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(menu);

        while (tempInput != null) {
            selection = Integer.parseInt(tempInput);

            if (selection == 1) {

                RenovationProjectManager menuOption1;
                menuOption1 = new RenovationProjectManager();

            } else if (selection == 2) {

                RenovationProjectManager menuOption2;
                menuOption2 = new RenovationProjectManager();
                menuOption2.menuOption2Scenario();

            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid choice!");
            }
            tempInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(menu);

        }

    }


    public RenovationProjectManager() {
        menuOption1Scenario();
    }

    public void menuOption1Scenario() {

        double wallArea = 0, cost, height, length, costPerSqm;
        String tempInput;

        costPerSqm = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter cost per sq.m ($)"));
        tempInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a wall name");
        height = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter " + tempInput + " wall height (m)"));
        length = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter " + tempInput + " wall length (m)"));

        wallArea = height * length;

        cost = wallArea * costPerSqm;

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Cost to paint " + tempInput + " wall of " + wallArea + " sq.m. is $" + cost);

    }


    public void menuOption2Scenario() {

        double wallArea = 0, cost, height, length, costPerSqm;
        String tempInput, wallNames;

        costPerSqm = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter cost per sq.m ($)"));
        wallNames = "";
        wallArea = 0;
        cost = 0;
        tempInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a wall name (cancel to finish)");
        while (tempInput != null) {

            height = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter " + tempInput + " wall height (m)"));
            length = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter " + tempInput + " wall length (m)"));

            wallArea += height * length;
            wallNames += tempInput + ", ";
            tempInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a wall name (cancel to finish)");
        }

            cost = wallArea * costPerSqm;

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Cost to paint " + wallNames + "wall(s) of " + wallArea + " sq.m. is $" + cost);
    }

}
```

When I tried running the program I got an error message (after I entered `1` or `2`) that read: `at RenovationProjectManager.<init>(RenovationProjectManager.java:63)`.

If you would like some more information/background just ask; thanks!

Comment: Your constructor is creating an instance of the same type - ` RenovationProjectManager menuOption1 = new RenovationProjectManager();` - leading to infinite chain of constructor calls.

Comment: @Eran oh; I wanted to call the menuOption1 method instead...

Comment: How do I call the menuOption1 method? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re creating two instances of the same object `menuOption1`, once in the `main` method and once in the constructor.   Remove the following line from the `main` method.  You only need to use your constructor to call the method.

```
RenovationProjectManager menuOption1 = new RenovationProjectManager();
```

Also, remove the object creation from the constructor.  You can call the method directly.

Inside your constructor just use

```
menuOption1Scenario();
```

Comment: yes, thanks for pointing that out! :) How would I fix it though? Thank you!

Comment: @CateZ.  Your assignment is to use the constructor to make the method calls, so remove the instantiation of menuOption1 from your main method.  I updated my answer.

Comment: However, I have 2 options for my menu; what should I do for the constructor method in that case?

Comment: @CateZ.  Your code is missing (unintentionally?) the method menuOption2Scenario();   The same constructor can call menuOption2Scenario(); the same way it called the first method if the method is in the same class.  Just place the second method under the first.  However, if the method is in another class (other than a parent class), you’ll need to create a constructor within this constructor to access your menuOption2Scenario() method.